# What does the keyboard shortcut ⌥⇞ mean?

Tags: keyboard, latex

I'm in need of a translator for <kbd>**⌥ ⇞**</kbd>

This screen shot below is from the TexStudio and Texmaker latex editors.

[image: screen capture of two glyphs]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**⌥** - Is the **Option** key, also called **Alt**.

**⇞** - It's called **Upwards Arrow with Double Stroke**, and usually represents *page up*. If your keyboard lacks that specific key, doing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> does the trick.

Comment: I can't understand why Apple's keyboards print the command symbol on the Command key, but don't print the option/alt and control symbols on their respective keys.